# Чтение файла построчно и разделение слов пробелами

Tags: golang, ssh, ос, split

У меня есть файл login.txt

```
10.0.0.1 bitnami C:/key/key.pem
158.98.32.1 admin C:/key/key.pem
32.42.192.1 user C:/key/key.pem
```

Мне нужно считать этот файл построчно и вставить считанные данные в ssh конфиг.
Только вот я не совсем понимаю как мне разделить считанную строку по пробелам и далее внести в ssh конфиг 1 к 1 к 1, чтоб было `Server: server, Username: username, Key: keypath`, и чтоб не было такого что у хоста `10.0.0.1` был другой юзернейм или ключ аутентификации.

Comment: а причем тут go?

Comment: Ну так используйте [strings.Split](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) и дальше в мап.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитать фаил, разделить сплитом построчно, а затем разделить каждую строку сплитом по проблелу)

```
func main() {

  type Config struct {
      Server   string
      Username string
      Key      string
  }

  configs := make([]Config, 0)

  configFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./config")

  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }

  configLines := strings.Split(string(configFile), "\n")

  for i := 0; i < len(configLines); i++ {

      if configLines[i] != "" {

          configLine := strings.Split(string(configLines[i]), " ")

          newConfig := Config{Server: configLine[0], Username: configLine[1], Key: configLine[2]}
          configs = append(configs, newConfig)
      }
  }

  for _, config := range configs {
      println(config.Server + " " + config.Username + " " + config.Key)
  }
}
```

Вывод:

```
10.0.0.1 bitnami C:/key/key.pem
158.98.32.1 admin C:/key/key.pem
32.42.192.1 user C:/key/key.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

просто замените input.txt на ваш файл. а output на конфиг `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```golang
import (
    "os"
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    lines, err := readLines("input.txt")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("readLines: %s", err)
    }

    var result []string
    for _, item := range lines {
        arr:= strings.Split(item, " ")
        result = append(result, "Server: " + arr[0] + ", Username: "+ arr[1] + ", Key: " + arr[2] );
    }
    writeLines(result, "output.txt")
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func readLines(path string) ([]string, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    var lines []string

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
    }
    return lines, scanner.Err()
}

func writeLines(lines []string, path string) error {
    file, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, line := range lines {
        file.WriteString(line + "\n")
    }

    return file.Close()
}
```